# Помогите составить запрос mysql с выборкой

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Добрый вечер. Есть 2 таблицы.
**contests: id, post_id, status** и **members: id, uid, post_id, won**

Помогите правильно составить запрос, чтобы получить такой ответ (в поле members должно быть указано 3 uid, то есть те, которые имею статус won = 1):
[image: Правильный ответ]

Сейчас я имею такой ответ (в поле members указаны все uid, а должны быть только те, которые имеют статус won = 1):
[image: Неправильный ответ]

Мой неправильный запрос:

```
SELECT contests.id, contests.post_id, contests.status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT members.uid ORDER BY members.uid ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS members
FROM `contests` contests
LEFT JOIN `members` members ON contests.post_id=members.post_id
GROUP BY contests.post_id;
```

Я пытаюсь сделать выборку по won = 1 и status = 1:

```
SELECT contests.id, contests.post_id, contests.status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT members.uid ORDER BY members.uid ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS members
FROM `contests` contests
WHERE members.won = 1 AND contests.status = 1
LEFT JOIN `members` members ON contests.post_id=members.post_id
GROUP BY contests.post_id;
```

Но получается ошибка:

```
Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "WHERE" at position 168)
```

Помогите правильно составить запрос. Спасибо.

Comment: `where` пишется после всех `join` поменяйте местами 3 и 4 строки

Comment: @Mike так просто? Спасибо большое!